Problem with rigify and full armature in Blender file
When rigging my character, the bones are able to move the mesh, but the generated rig cant move it. I'm not sure what's causing the problem here as all my normals are facing the correct way, and the bones can move the mesh on their own. I've attached the file below.



You don't appear to have provided a link to your file although you say that you've attached it.
